# From a stream operation, how do I map a set of values to anoter value?

Tags: java, csv, java-stream, mapping

This is a modified Person class named `CavePerson`. It has no getters, but does have variables that correspond to indexes in a CSV/Excel file. Each `CavePerson` has a number, name, gender, and the year they were introduced in.

```java
public class CavePerson {
   public final int num;
   public final String name;
   public final String gender;
   public final int intro_year;

   public CavePerson (int aNum, String aName, String aGender, int anIntro_year){
      this.num = aNum;
      this.name = aName;
      this.gender = aGender;
      this.intro_year = anIntro_year;
   }

   public static CavePerson lineValues(String line) {
      String array = line.split(",");
      int numA = array[0];
      String nameA = array[1];
      String genderA array[2];
      int intro_yearA = array[3];
      return new CavePerson(numA, nameA, genderA, intro_yearA);
   }
}
```

Each line in this `cavepeople.csv` file is a `CavePerson` object:

| Num | Name | Gender | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fred | Male | 1960 |
| 2 | Wilma | Female | 1960 |
| 3 | Barney | Male | 1961 |
| 4 | Betty | Female | 1961 |
| 5 | Dino | Male | 1964 |
| 6 | BamBam | Male | 1966 |
| 7 | Puss | Male | 1967 |
| 8 | Pebbles | Female | 1966 |

I am practicing streams, and I wanted to get a count of each gender that was introduced by each year. The expected result return a map of each year and list the number of male/female characters that were introduced that year. It should look like this:

`1960, Male 1, Female 1`

This is what I have so far. From a `Stream`, I map each year to the count of each gendered character, but I am getting a type error stating that I cannot convert `Map<Object,Long>` to my desired `Map<Integer, Map<String,Long>>`

```java
Function<Stream<CavePerson>, Map<Integer, Map<String, Long>>> getGenderByYear = 
    e -> e.map(x -> x.year)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy((CavePerson-> CavePerson.gender), Collectors.counting()));
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `Avenger` class is what you wrote as `CavePerson` ? If it is, then using `e.map(x -> x.year)` you are converting the `Stream<Avenger>` to a `Stream<Integer>`. After that you cannot have operations on the avenger object .

Comment: I'll fix that so it is less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function takes an input as `Stream<CavePerson>`. So once you do the `e.map(x -> x.year)`, the Stream is converted to `Stream<Integer>`. After this you cannot access the properties of the cave person object, because you have converted the stream to a different type. So what you had to do was:

1. Group the stream by `year`.
2. Within each year, do an additional grouping based on `gender`.
3. Now apply the function to your list.

Note: assume static imports for `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.counting()`:

```java
Function<Stream<CavePerson>, Map<Integer, Map<String, Long>>> mapper
    = str -> str.collect(groupingBy(c -> c.year, 
                                    groupingBy(c -> c.gender, counting())));
```